# Drawing in drawRect is always called but doesn't always produce anything

Tags: iphone, cgcontext

I'm having a strange issue at the moment. I'm generating a drawing in a UIViewControllers UIView which calls drawRect:, goes through the entire code process without crashing but produces nothing. If I click on a UI object inside of the UIView the drawRect gets reloaded and my image appears.

The only good thing with this is that it happens every time at first load but it also happens some times later.

This usually works so am I missing something like a reload/set function?

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextClearRect(context, rect);
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1, 1, 1, 1.0f);
CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor); 
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5.0);

CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 20, 20);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 40, 40);   
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

Comment: Why are you calling `UIGraphicsEndImageContext()`?

Comment: Good point, that was part of some old code, issue still remains

Answer (score 1):

Is your code calling `-drawRect:` directly? If so, *stop that*. Before calling `-drawRect:`, UIView sets up the drawing context so that all your `-drawRect:` override has to do is draw. If you try to call that method directly the drawing context won't be set up correctly and your drawing will end up in the wrong place, or nowhere at all. The drawing works correctly for you when you let the system manage drawing, in which case the context will be properly set before `-drawRect:` is called.

Comment: Yeh I'm currently calling it through `setNeedsDisplayInRect` and before that just `setNeedsDisplay`

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like your `drawRect:` code is not getting called when you expect it to be. Be sure you are calling `setNeedsDisplay` on your UIView as needed.

Comment: Yep, it is being called by `setNeedsDisplayInRect`: but still nothing